# Extract polygon pixels using lazy reading in rasterio

Tags: python, rasterio

I have several hundred tif files of ~50mb each where I need to read only a few hundred pixels within a polygon. I currently do this by loading each tif into memory and using `rasterio.features.geometry_mask` to get the pixels of interest. But reading in the large tifs takes a very long time.

```
import fiona
import rasterio

with fiona.open('polygon.geojson') as f:
    geom=f[0]['geometry']

all_data=[]
for tif_filename in tif_file_list:
    with rasterio.open(tif_filename) as raster_obj:
        polygon_mask = rasterio.features.geometry_mask(geometries=[geom],
                                               out_shape=(raster_obj.height, raster_obj.width),
                                               transform=raster_obj.transform,
                                               all_touched=False,
                                               invert=True)

        all_data.append(raster_obj.read()[polygon_mask])
```

Is there any way I can use the Window option to only read the portion of the raster I want? For example I can read just the extent of the area of interest:

```
with fiona.open('polygon.geojson') as f:
    b = f.bounds

polygon_window = rasterio.windows.from_bounds(left=b[0],
                                              bottom=b[1], 
                                              right=b[2], 
                                              top=b[3], 
                                              transform = raster_obj.transform)

extent_data = raster_obj.read(1, window=polygon_window)
```

This takes a fraction of the time, but I can't figure out how to then get the pixel data from only within the polygon.

Comment: Use the Affine object to translate from pixel's (centre) row,col to x,y coordinates for each pixel. Check with fiona if that point is inside your polygon.

Comment: you might want to use a VRT to access the sub tiff data

Answer (score 3):

It wasn't clear to me what you wanted initially. You basically need to create a raster mask from your polygon with the same resolution as your tiff.

You should check out [rasterstats](http://pythonhosted.org/rasterstats/). If you're willing to install the package, it's as simple as feeding the raster and the polygon with "raster_out" flag set to True. Then you get exactly your pixels within the polygon.

If you are averse to installing the package for some reason, the relevant portions are

```
with Raster(raster, affine, nodata, band_num) as rast:
    features_iter = read_features(vectors, layer)
    for i, feat in enumerate(features_iter):
        geom = shape(feat['geometry'])

        if 'Point' in geom.type:
            geom = boxify_points(geom, rast)

        geom_bounds = tuple(geom.bounds)

        fsrc = rast.read(bounds=geom_bounds)

        # create ndarray of rasterized geometry
        rv_array = rasterize_geom(geom, like=fsrc, all_touched=all_touched)
```

"geom" is a shapely geometry object. "fsrc" is the initial raster you created (extent_data). The function "rasterize_geom" is as follows:

```
from rasterio import features
def rasterize_geom(geom, like, all_touched=False):
    geoms = [(geom, 1)]
    rv_array = features.rasterize(
        geoms,
        out_shape=like.shape,
        transform=like.affine,
        fill=0,
        all_touched=all_touched)
    return rv_array
```

If you're trying to compute statistics, you can use [rasterstats](http://pythonhosted.org/rasterstats/), which is built on rasterio. Your question didn't quite specify which pixels you're looking for, but rasterstats will load only the portions of the raster you need and create a mask for pixels outside that polygon. I haven't tried it, but I see from digging around the code that you can supply a shapefile of points as well as polygons.

If you're in a conda environment, install with

```
conda install -c conda-forge rasterstats
```

Comment: `extent_data` is a numpy array, so there are no methods in it to geo-reference the area within the polygon. I took a quick look at rasterstats but I don't see anything in the documentation that suggests it doesn't read the entire tif.

Comment: @Shawn `rasterstats` only reads in the pixels for the extent of each geometry. See the [source](https://github.com/perrygeo/python-rasterstats/blob/master/src/rasterstats/main.py#L155) of the `rasterstats.gen_zonal_stats` function.

Comment: @Shawn I didn't understand what you were asking initially. See my edited answer for the relevant portions of rasterstats.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @Jon, I ended up using the `Raster` module in `rasterstats` to get what I wanted. This code only reads the portion of the raster which is within the bounds of the polygon, which cuts the reading time down a *lot*. While I could use the `zonal_stats` function in rasterstats, I wanted to pull *all* pixel values for further processing elsewhere.

```
import rasterio
import fiona
from rasterstats.io import Raster

with fiona.open('polygon.geojson') as f:
    geom_bounds = f.bounds
    geom=f[0]['geometry']

all_data=[]
for tif_filename in tif_file_list:
    with Raster(tif_filename) as raster_obj:
        raster_subset = raster_obj.read(bounds=geom_bounds) 
        polygon_mask = rasterio.features.geometry_mask(geometries=[geom],
                                               out_shape=(raster_subset.shape[0], 
                                                          raster_subset.shape[1]),
                                               transform=raster_subset.affine,
                                               all_touched=False,
                                               invert=True)

        all_data.append(raster_subset.array[polygon_mask])
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, if you use rasterstats (without computing any stats) and the "raster_out" flag set to true, you _do_  get back the raster and its mask, i.e. all the pixel values. But glad you found a solution!